# Unable to enter BIOS in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, bios

I was using desktop running on a 64 bit Windows 7 professional, I trying to enter BIOS to check the virtualization setting, when I boot or restart my desktop, before enter Windows, I don't see any screen or instruction to entering BIOS.

I wonder is it I didn't install BIOS on the machine or?  How can I check whether BIOS exist or it is come together upon installing mother board driver?  Please advise.

Comment: The BIOS isn't something you install, it's stored in a ROM chip on the motherboard.  A machine without a BIOS cannot boot.

Comment: [Hello and welcome to the 1990s!  We don't use ROM chips nowadays. ☺](http://superuser.com/questions/347115)  If poor old `sams5817` picks up xyr mainboard and looks over it for a ROM chip, xe won't find the right chip, if xe indeed finds any ROM at all.

Comment: Agree, but why xe?

Comment: @Dehumanizer because it is not readily obvious whether the OP is male or female. I don’t know much about Malay names, but in English at least, Sam(s?) could be either. Perhaps a more obvious placeholder (at least for computer aficionados) would be `*he` or `.*he`.

Comment: *> A machine without a BIOS cannot boot*   @Wyzard, it could have an [EFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface).

Comment: @Synetech, people often call it "the BIOS" even when it's actually EFI.  I tend to use the more general term "firmware", but I still say "BIOS" sometimes when the distinction isn't important.

Comment: @Synetech, but [CMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS) actually refers to hardware, not software (or firmware).  Lots of things are CMOS.  :-)

Comment: @Wyzard, yes but with computers, the BIOS/EFI is the main CMOS. I don't think I've ever heard anyone refer to any other kind.

Comment: @Synetech, did you read the wiki page I linked?  CMOS is how most modern ICs (chips) are made.  Your CPU is CMOS.  So is your GPU, and your network interface, and your SATA controller, and probably all the other major components in your computer.  The memory that holds your system's configuration is called "CMOS RAM" only because long ago when that term was introduced, CMOS technology was new and shiny rather than commonplace.  (It's like calling your audio equipment a "stereo", as if anyone has mono rigs anymore.)

Comment: @Wyzard, like I said, in the computer-repair field, the BIOS/EFI is the *main* CMOS. I have never heard anyone refer to anything other than the BIOS/EFI when using the term CMOS in regards to fixing computers.

Comment: @Synetech, I know.  My point was that it's technically inaccurate *despite* the common usage.  Much like using the term "BIOS" to refer to an EFI.  :-)

Comment: @Wyzard how is telling someone to clear the CMOS technically (or otherwise) inaccurate? Most motherboards have a *CLRCMOS* jumper… or maybe manufacturers don’t know what they’re doing?

Comment: @Synetech, because every chip in the machine is manufactured using CMOS technology.  The one that holds the system settings is not the "main" one.  It's just the one that most people, who don't know what CMOS *is*, associate with that term for historical reasons.  Manufacturers continue to use the term because it's the one people are familiar with.

Comment: @Wyzard *> because every chip in the machine is manufactured using CMOS technology*   I read you the first time.   *> Manufacturers continue to use the term because it's the one people are familiar with.*   You just repeated what I said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every computer motherboard has BIOS installed on it, but it may be hard to see what key you need to press to enter the BIOS itself.

Traditionally, the <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, or one of the function keys (<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>) are designated to take you into the BIOS.

If you know the motherboard model you can also check the documentation on the manufacturer's web site.

Answer (score 2):

If it s a name brand board, you can look on the board for the manufacture and the model number, then go online and get the manual. Otherwise, if all else fails, or if it is a HP/DELL/etc, check the motherboard and look for a jumper. It usually has the word CMOS next to it. Changing the jumper to the other pins for a minute, then changing it back, should reset the bios so it will display the default boot screen which will tell you what key to press to get into the bios. Usually if a machine doesn't display anything and immediately boots Windows, then the options to display the boot messages is turned off. On newer Intel boards, setting the features for quick boot requires resetting the jumper in order to get the bios key to register.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make the BIOS generate an error condition:

1. Just hold down several keys on the keyboard, this will slow down the first screen and might error.
2. Disconnect the keyboard or mouse, some BIOS are configured by default to give a warning.